# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined' while rendering data from AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to render an array of data by getting value from AsyncStorage. But render gets called first and shows `map of undefined` while i'm trying to map the array. Here's the code :

```js
const [myCosts, setMyCosts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('useeffect')
        readData();
      }, [])

      
const readData = async () => {
        try {
          const expenseValue =  await AsyncStorage.getItem('COSTLIST')
          setMyCosts(expenseValue);
       
        } catch (e) {
          alert('Failed to fetch the data from storage')
        }
      }
if (myCosts === []) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.activityIndicatorContainer}>
      <ActivityIndicator animating={true}/>
    </View>
  );
} else {
 return(
  <View>
  {myCosts.map(cost => {
       return (
          <Text style={{backgroundColor:'#f2e3df',color:'#000',padding:10}}>
             {cost.name}
           </Text>
        )
  })
  }
  </View>
 )
}
```

I have added condition too. But still it's giving the error. What else can be done?

Comment: Clearly, as of `setMyCosts(expenseValue);` , `expenseValue` is `undefined`. So that's what you need to debug.

Comment: Side note: This check will always fail: `if (myCosts === []) {` Arrays are objects, no array is `=== []` because no other array is the same array as the one you're creating with `[]`. If you want to check for an empty array, you can use `if (!myCosts.length) {` or `if (myCosts.length === 0) {`

Comment: expenseValue is not undefined. If i try to map then it shows undefined otherwise it shows data fine on console. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: In the code you've shown, literally the only way to get the `map` error you describe is if `expenseValue` is `undefined` in that call. So either the problem is in code you haven't shown, or `expenseValue` is `undefined` in that call.

Answer (score 0):

You wanna make sure your AsyncStorage is not empty before setting it to state.

This should help you fix the error.

```js
const expenseValue =  await AsyncStorage.getItem('COSTLIST')

setMyCosts(expenseValue || []);
```

However, you want to make sure you have `COSTLIST` set properly in your `AsyncStorage` so it doesn't return `undefined`

Comment: The weird part is that expenseValue is getting value but if i try to map, then it shows error.@fortunee

Comment: How do you know it's getting expesiveValue?

Comment: When i console.log after AsyncStorage get i see data on the console.

Comment: Try using an if statement like this `if (expensiveValue) setMyCosts(expensiveValue)`

Answer (score 0):

Why you are setting the state when you can do something like this; useState set method is an asynchronous call, it may not reflect the changes immediately

```
let myCosts = [];

useEffect(() => {
    readData();
}, [])
      
const readData = async () => {
        try {
          myCosts =  await AsyncStorage.getItem('COSTLIST') || [];
        } catch (e) {
          alert('Failed to fetch the data from storage')
        }
}

if (myCosts.length) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.activityIndicatorContainer}>
      <ActivityIndicator animating={true}/>
    </View>
  );
} else {
 return(
  <View>
  {myCosts.map(cost => {
       return (
          <Text style={{backgroundColor:'#f2e3df',color:'#000',padding:10}}>
             {cost.name}
           </Text>
        )
  })
  }
  </View>
 )
}
```

Comment: I need to keep in state because i will have more dynamic data incoming which i need to add to the array.

Comment: Good refactor, but you don't wanna `return` on `else`, and you also needed to check if `!myCosts.length` as opposed to just `myCosts.length`